# css styling a loading message

Tags: html, css

Im using ajax to load some content. I do not have problem with that, I just want to know how can I style the 'loading...' message or preferably use a loader image, at the center of the screen. While content is loading the 'loading' message appear at the top left corner(leaving the entire page black ) and it does not look nice.. I was wondering if it possible.

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "page1.php", 
   beforeSend: function () {
  $("#content").html('loading...');
    },
   data: "Id="+Id,
   success: function(msg){
     $("#content").html(msg);
   }
   });
```

Where `#content` is the wrapper div for my page below the header (right side) and the header which contains the nav menu is styled to float left with a vertical alignment and width 250px. The template is 1200 X 700.. I tried to wrap `#content` with a `#loader` div but its not working.. any advise is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add an id to the 'loading' while doing the request and have the css handle it:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "page1.php", 
   beforeSend: function () {
    $("#loading").addClass("activated");
    },
   data: "Id="+Id,
   success: function(msg){
     $("#loading").removeClass("activated");
     $("#content").html(msg);
   }
   });
```

To center an element with css:

[Quick CSS Trick: How To Center an Object Exactly In The Center](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).